# WPF exception running animation in another class

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I can run an animation from the main window class but if I try to run the same code from another class in the same namespace I receive an exception in the storyboard begin function
this is the exception:
No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'DefaultGroup'.

this is how I set the storyboard target and property

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(r3d,"DefaultGroup");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(r3d, new PropertyPath("(Visual3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)"));
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks
Walther

Comment: What happens if you try 'r3d.SetValue(<r3d's type>.DefaultGroup, new PropertyPath(...));'?

Comment: I receive an error : Error2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.Rotation3DAnimationUsingKeyFrames' to 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty' 
I think I am close but I have one wrong parameter
thanks for your help

Comment: This is because your object "DefaultGroup" is not registered in any xaml namescope so wpf can't found it when you call the code from another place. You have to register your object and animation in the same xaml namescope (in a style, a template etc.) Refer to the MSDN link for class "Namescope" to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

--otherUserControl.cs

```
StackPanel defaultGroup;
```

--MainWindow.cs

```
this.RegisterName(otherUserControl.defaultGroup.Name, otherUserControl.defaultGroup); // RegisterName

Storyboard.SetTargetName(r3d,"defaultGroup");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(r3d, new PropertyPath("(Visual3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)"));
```